# Removing words in a string Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, text, replace

I am attempting to remove words in a line/string in Powershell. I've attempted the -replace operator in a few different ways without a result. The data that needs to be removed is in a text file with quite a few lines, each line has Data: Primary: and then an Azure Storage Account Key. I'm running another script that will loop through this txt for the storage account keys to run some commands.

The data in the line looks like this: 
data:    Primary: asdflkajsdflkj/$asdfASDFasdf

I need to remove 'data:' 'Primary:' and any white space before the first letter.

Below is my script:

```
$getAccessKey = Get-Content 'file path'
$getAccessKey | ForEach-Object{
    azure storage account keys list $_
} | Set-Content 'file path'

Get-Content 'file path' | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Primary'} | Set-Content 'file path'
Get-Content 'file path' | Where-Object {$_ -replace ".*:"} | Set-Content 'file path'
```

The below script is the one I attempted before:

```
$getAccessKey = Get-Content 'file path'
$getAccessKey | ForEach-Object{
    azure storage account keys list $_
} | Set-Content 'file path'

Get-Content 'file path' | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Primary'} | Set-Content 'file path'
Get-Content 'file path' | Where-Object {$_ -replace "Data:"} | Set-Content 'file path'
```

Neither of these scripts are getting a result, it appears though its not picking up the ':' or the text 'Data:'

Comment: If you're parsing storage keys, why not either save them in a format that you can more easily parse or pick them up directly from from Azure?

Comment: I'm attempting to create a way to where I never have to do this again or go to azure to get the keys to get the information I'm looking for. Given 100+ storage accounts and subsequent shares, it can take quite a bit of time to check the size of file shares. That and I would like to automate the process and have it grab any new shares/accounts that are created in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well good news, I figured out the answer to my own question after fiddling around for a minutes.

```
$getAccessKey = Get-Content 'file path'
$getAccessKey | ForEach-Object{
azure storage account keys list $_
} | Set-Content 'file path'

Get-Content 'file path' | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Primary'} | Set-Content 'file path'
Get-Content 'file path' | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "\w{4}:\s+\w{7}:\s+", ""} | Set-Content 'file path'
```

Answer (score 0):

Going from your comment, a much better solution would be running something like this

```
$StorageAccountKeys = @{}
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | `
    foreach {$StorageAccountKeys.Add($_.StorageAccountName, `
    ((Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName `
    $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.StorageAccountName).Key1)) }
```

This will create an object with all of the Storage account names and keys in a subscription.

```
Name           Value
----           -----
storagename    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-storagekey-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
storagename1    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-storagekey1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
storagename 2   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-storagekey2-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Which you can either access with a foreach, or a by using `$StorageAccountKeys.storagename`

Comment: That didn't quite work the way I wanted it to. But I figured it out. Thank you very much for your assistance.